# How to visualize Neo4J graph in Neo4J Bloom the same as in Neo4J Browser

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I would like to inspect my Neo4J graph in Neo4J Bloom, since I can edit the node appearances (e.g. icons) in Bloom, which is not possible in Neo4J Browser.

However, when I visualize my graph in Neo4J Bloom, the graph appearance is very different compared to Neo4J Browser, even though the nodes and relationships are exactly the same.

In Neo4J Browser, the the spacing between the nodes allows to see the graph structure with its clusters very clearly:

[image]

But when I visualize the same graph in Neo4J Bloom, the graph looks very compressed with very little spacing between nodes and no clearly identifiable clusters:

[image]

For reproducibility: the graph in this example is the default Neo4J graph of the pre-installed "Movie DBMS" in the Example project.

How can I change the Neo4J Bloom visualization to match the Neo4J Browser style?